# Unit testing RxJava repeatWhen operator always stuck on the first iteration

Tags: android, unit-testing, asynchronous, rx-java, robolectric

I'm trying to unit test my viewmodel code, which does a server polling to return data as soon as its `Status == ELIGIBLE`

My problem is, it always assert when it's still loading (repeating), and not waiting for the `onSuccess` to be called to assert the correct status.

I've put some logs to track what's happening:

```
doOnSubscribe called
repeatWhen called
doOnNext called
takeUntil called
doOnNext called
takeUntil called
```

As you can see, `repeatWhen` and `takeUntil` are called twice (which is expected), but after that, no `onSuccess` called.

And eventually the test fails with this message
`Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<SUCCESS> but was:<LOADING>`

If I removed the failing line, the next assertion would fail too with message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :ELIGIBLE
Actual   :null
```

Which mean the `onSuccess` method is not yet reached, and is still loading.

I also don't prefer using `Schedulers.trampoline()` .. it works, but it waits for 5 secs synchronously. I prefer to use `TestScheduler.advanceByTime()` instead.

Here's the client code:

```
fun startStatusPolling() {
    val pollingSingle = shiftPayService.obtainCardStatus()
            .repeatWhen {
                println("repeatWhen called")
                //POLLING_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 5
                it.delay(POLLING_INTERVAL_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }
            .takeUntil { item ->
                println("takeUntil called")
                item.cardStatus != Status.PENDING
            }.doOnNext {
                println("doOnNext called")
            }
            .lastElement()
            .toSingle()

    subscribe(pollingSingle, pollingStatusLiveData)
}
```

And my test class:

```
@RunWith(HomebaseRobolectricTestRunner::class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
class CardViewModelTest {

    lateinit var viewModel: CardViewModel
    var testScheduler = TestScheduler()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }

        val cardStatusPending: CardStatus = mockk(relaxed = true) {
            every { status } returns Status.PENDING
        }

        val cardStatusEligible: CardStatus = mockk(relaxed = true) {
            every { status } returns Status.ELIGIBLE
        }

        val cardService: CardService = spyk {
            every { obtainCardStatus() } returnsMany listOf(
                    Single.just(cardStatusPending),
                    Single.just(cardStatusEligible)
            )
        }

        viewModel = CardViewModel(cardService)
    }

    @Test
    fun testCardStatusPolling() {
        viewModel.startStatusPolling()
        shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idle()

        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        //after 5 sec delay, single is resubscibed, returning the second single cardStatusEligible
        assertEquals(Result.Status.SUCCESS, viewModel.pollingStatusLiveData.value?.status)
        assertEquals(EligiblityStatus.ELIGIBLE, viewModel.pollingStatusLiveData.value?.data?.eligibilityStatus)

    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/b9177673e9c28418a119cf1215e93521) works for me. Perhaps you mocked the wrong objects or you have to use `setMainThreadSchedulerHandler` instead of `setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler`.